# pip install creates directory in site-packages but not in bin directory

Tags: python3, pip, virtualenv

I want to install a python-package (celery) within a virtualenv using pip. My virtualenv is activated, and after executing

```
pip install celery
```

the directory `venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/` has been created. However, when I try to execute celery, I get an error message saying it is not installed, and it doesn't exist in `venv/bin/`, while it does exist on my Arch Linux installation where I (probably :O) did the same thing... Any hints?

Comment: `sudo -H pip install celery` ?

Answer (score 2):

Usually you `pip install` anything either with `sudo` systemwide:

```
sudo pip install celery
```

or with `--user` locally in home directory:

```
pip install --user celery
```

Comment: Will try it with sudo tomorrow, but since I am in a virtualenv, shouldn't pip install install it "systemwide" in my virtualenv without requiring sudo since it is all within my venv?

Comment: [Here](https://www.dabapps.com/blog/introduction-to-pip-and-virtualenv-python/) is a nice explanation how to use `pip` in `virtualenv`. Apparently you will need to make sure that you use the correct python version with it. `To use the versions of python and pip inside the environment, type env/bin/python and env/bin/pip respectively.`

Comment: Thanks for the tips, however, what I was doing is exactly what you describe. Instead of using env/bin/python, I activated the virtualenv (as described in your link) and within the virtualenv I can install it using pip install celery without sudo. It had something to do with the python version I was using, I forced virtualenv to use a custom built python3.6. With the python 3.5 that ships with ubuntu it works...